# Есть ли геттеры и сеттеры в Elixir или есть другие варианты?

Tags: функциональное-программирование, elixir

Извините ребята за глупый вопрос, я знаю что Elixir это функциональный язык программирования, но мне просто очень хочется узнать как сделать не используя get/set.
Задача такая,к примеру у нас, есть переменная и мы хотим сохранять только определенной длины текстовое значения. Вот к примеру как я сделал на Dart, пожалуйста ребята не судите меня строго. Мне просто интересно можно такой вариант сделать Elixir

```
class X {
  String Zem = "";
  String get xx {
    return Zem;
  }

  set xx(String sum) {
    if (sum.length < 5) {
      print("No");
    } else {
      this.Zem = sum;
      print("Welcom ${Zem.toUpperCase()}");
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  X c = new X();
  c.xx = "xamarin";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Elixir используется [акторная модель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) с [иммутабельными](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) структурами данных, поэтому для решения подобной задачи может использоваться абстракция, которая называется [Agent](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Agent.html).

```
defmodule X do
  use Agent

  def start_link(initial_value) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> initial_value end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def get do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, & &1)
  end

  def set(new_value) do
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, fn _ -> new_value end)
  end
end
```

Далее можно использовать этот агент из любого места в проекте примерно вот так:

```
X.start_link("") # {:ok, #PID<0.126.0>}
X.get()          # ""
X.set("xamarin") # :ok
X.get()          # "xamarin"
```

Comment: Вы меня извините за наглость,  но вы могли бы привести пример, как реализовать именно как здесь, но только на Elixir class X {
  String Zem = "";
  String get xx {
    return Zem;
  }

  set xx(String sum) {
    if (sum.length < 5) {
      print("No");
    } else {
      this.Zem = sum;
      print("Welcom ${Zem.toUpperCase()}");
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  X c = new X();
  c.xx = "xamarin";
}

Comment: Тут не очень удобно писать код в комментариях. Но, с другой стороны, я уверен, что с этим кодом по моему примеру Вы сможете справиться самостоятельно, если попробуете :)